# Font size in Internet Explorer is different

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following css

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%; // 100% is 16px, this value will 10px
}
```

when I am checking the text on the page in every other browser, it gives me `10px`. But Internet Explorer 11 gives `9.93px`.

As I understand, it is happening, because IE [truncates fractional values](http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/), interpreting my property actually as `font-size: 62%`.

Here is a demo, that you can try: https://jsfiddle.net/vcod81vy/

Do you have any ideas how can I make it consistent?

P.S. I can't use hard-coded `10px` value, because I have a requirement to build accessible web interface that supports font overrides from browser settings, like it is described [here](http://andy-carter.com/blog/using-scalable-css-units-for-font-sizes)

Comment: What is the version of IE used? According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530759(v=vs.85).aspx the floating point value is accepted. If this behavior is still existing in latest IE versions, try using calc()?

Comment: updated the question, I am supporting only latest IE11, the problem still exists.
Could you elaborate on the `calc` approach?

Comment: I am not IE-pro, but calc() performs a calculation and accepts pixels and percentages. See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp. I am not sure but maybe you can trick IE's behavior... If it helped I will post as answer.

Comment: can you use vw,vh instead of % ?

Comment: @Fabien, I tried to set `font-size: calc(10em / 16)`, it works. Are there any downsides of this approach instead of percentage?

Comment: I don't think there is any downside to it, except maybe (a lot) older browser support. I will add this as an answer, if you can validate it it is nice from you :-)

Comment: Yes, thank you! Will try to go with this solution to the production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530759(v=vs.85).aspx the floating point value is accepted.

If this behavior is still existing in latest IE versions, try using calc().

Solution found was: `font-size: calc(10em / 16)`

There is no downside to `calc()` except that older browsers might not support it very well.