# background size in rem causes problems in ie11 and edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I have an icon that I want to add a background size in rem so it can be resized when augmenting the font-size of the website :

https://codepen.io/stephendesjardins/project/full/ZjVOMG

I have this css  :

```
.box {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}
.box:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: .25rem;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(../icon.svg);
    width: 1.1875rem;
    height: 1.1875rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1.1875rem 1.1875rem;
}
```

here is the icon :

```
<svg version="1.1" id="ic-liens" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 19 19" xml:space="preserve"><path id="fleche" fill="#007944" d="M6.5 4.986l4.472 4.513L6.5 14.012l1.069 1.538L13.5 9.499 7.569 3.55z"/><path id="cercle" fill="#007944" d="M9.5 0C4.3 0 0 4.3 0 9.5S4.3 19 9.5 19 19 14.7 19 9.5 14.7 0 9.5 0zm0 17.3c-4.3 0-7.8-3.5-7.8-7.8s3.5-7.8 7.8-7.8 7.8 3.5 7.8 7.8-3.5 7.8-7.8 7.8z"/></svg>
```

in chrome it renders fine : 
[image]
but it ie11 it renders like this : 
[image]

It seems to be caused by the background size in rem. If I add pixels it's fine. If I add the website with a base font-size of 10 the rem works.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: also happens when `background-size: contain;`, `cover` or `100%` is used not just `rem`'s

Comment: yeah very weird bug...thanks for testing

Comment: I've tested your code on my side and reproduce the issue.It seems that Edge and IE could not read rem well. It may be a bug. I'll provide the feedback regarding this issue to MS Edge developers. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks do you work at Microsoft @JeniferJiang ?

Comment: Does it happen with an image file too or just an svg? I would guess it's got something to do with the SVG parser more than `background-size`

Comment: Yeah it's definitely with svg that this is causing problems rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that IE11 will truncate any values to two decimal places. You can test it by typing, for example, `width`: 1.1875rem and `height`: 1.1815rem, in your IE11 debugger and the both values will go to 1.18rem.

The icon image clipping under IE11 is most likely due to this rounding error. By truncating 1.1875rem to 1.18rem, you lost 0.0075rem in `width` and `height`. Under a `base-fontsize` = 10, this corresponds to a loss of 0.075px. For `base-fontsize` = 16, for example, this loss increases to 0.12px and might affect the display of your images.

To solve this problem, I propose that you use a function calculate $rem from $pixel by using a *ceil*() function, as shown in the following mathematical equation:

`rem` = *ceil*(`pixel`/`base-fontsize`*100)/100;

Now, your `width` = `height` = 1.1875rem will round up 1.19rem and will give a bit more room to your image and display properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

https://gist.github.com/vielhuber/34c3d9a0b424b14928e496f898265b3a

First convert all svgs to pngs:

```
find . -name '*.svg' -type f -exec svgexport {} "{}".png 300: \;
```

Then dynamically switch them in case of IE/Edge with the help of Apache:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Trident|MSIE|Edge [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(svg)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.png -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.png [QSA,L
```

I've never found another solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and found this page. I thought this workaround may be useful.

First, I found out that this problem occurs when the width/height of SVG is a decimal value, such as 15.8px. Even if I used `px`, this problem occurred. `rem` itself is not the direct cause.

Then the following setting is written in many sites for using rem.

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%; /* = 10px */
}
```

However, this leads to a decimal base font size (the `font-size` of the `html` element), so the width/height of SVG will also become a decimal value.
To avoid this, the following is presented in another question.
[Font size in Internet Explorer is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060854/font-size-in-internet-explorer-is-different)

```
html {
  font-size: calc(10em / 16)
}
```

Finally, you will be able to use rem as long as you set the width/height as a positive integer.